# Javascript to check all checkboxes with the same ID when one is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I am trying to make a simple javascript to mark as checked all checkboxes with the same ID once you check one of them. The problem comes from there that first state the checkbox is unchecked when I check it it works, when I uncheck it it works it does uncheck all the boxes with the same ID again but after that if I try to check it again it does not work.

Here is my code so far:

```
$('input[id="check_01"]').on('click',function(){
    $('input[id="check_01"]').attr('checked', $(this).is(':checked'))
});
```

Let me know what the logic of this should be to fix it? In JS Fiddle it works perfectly but not on my web form.

this is the input's code:

```
<input type="checkbox"  class="aboveage6" id="check_01"  name="utilities[]" value="1 parking"  /> 12<br />
<input type="checkbox"  class="aboveage6" id="check_01"  name="utilities_02[]" value="1 parqueo"  /> 12 2<br />
```

Comment: This cannot work. ID's are unique. Please use datasets or class names for this.

Comment: With classes it works the same way, first time checked and unchecked works, second is not working.

Comment: Correct. There's a difference between `prop` and `attr`. That's causing this script to malfunction. However it's strongly recommend to use unique IDs.

Comment: on the ID http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2 and http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute so no change in HTML5

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
$('input.check01').on('click', function() {
    $('input.check01').prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked') );

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="aboveage6 check01" id="check1" name="utilities[]" value="1 parking" />12
<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="aboveage6 check01" id="check2" name="utilities_02[]" value="1 parqueo" />12 2
<br />
```

This should do it.

Changed the ids. They're now unique. When clicked it will select all checkboxes with the same class and selects/unselects them.

Your original code with selecting on ID would also work, but it is not recommended and allowed according to the specs. You need to change the function `attr` to `prop`.

Answer (score 2):

Ids are unique, you shall change them. You can select all checkboxes and add the `click` event handler, then find all the ids starting with `check` using the `^=` operator and set their checked property using `prop`, this way the functionality works all ways.

**Edit - attr vs prop**

The property reflects the current ‘checked` value inside the check box, whereas the checked attribute contains the initial state of the checkbox from the HTML source code.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('input[type=checkbox]').on('click', function(){

        $('input[id^=check]').prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));

    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox"  class="aboveage6" id="check1"  name="utilities[]" value="1 parking"  /> 12<br />
<input type="checkbox"  class="aboveage6" id="check2"  name="utilities_02[]" value="1 parqueo"  /> 12 2<br />
```

Comment: This should be done by usings datasets or class names. Using IDs like this will be too prone to errors when the application becomes larger. Also OP asked for elements with the SAME ID to be checked/unchecked.

Comment: This is your opinion, you can keep it for yourself. You can always find specific checboxes within divisions or forms and catch then do the same checkbox related selection. Classes are good also but can also become probe if the application becomes larger.

Comment: For the first part true, but still your answer doesn't answer the OP's question.

Comment: Well the functionality is as requested and I have changed the attr to prop as well so it does address the requirements. I shifted the selection to become relative to the ids and not the classes cause this is what the OP wants `mark as checked all checkboxes with the same ID once you check one of them.`

Comment: Yep, but your checkboxes don't have the same ID

Comment: This is what you shall be calling prone dude, html elements shall never have same ids. So this is the whole idea about it. That's why I made this workaround. Besides, the property reflects the current ‘checked` value inside the check box, whereas the `checked` attribute contains the initial state of the checkbox from the HTML source code. So please be reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

As @Mouser said, ids are unique. Instead, you could give those inputs a class that is unique to that set of checkboxes. I don't know if you use it elsewhere, but your "aboveage6" class might work. And then in your jQuery, replace `'input[id="check_01"]'` with `'input.aboveage6'`. Or you can replace aboveage6 with whatever class name you need.